# What is the technical name for the "cap" on the multimeter probe's banana plug (or socket)?

Tags: multimeter, probe, banana-jack

Unlike the test leads that come with most portable, pocket size multimeters, the benchtop multimeter's test probe I had has a "cap" that sits tightly on and covers the banana plug. I'm thinking it would be a nice idea to also mount these caps on the banana sockets on my benchtop multimeter's and not to leave them all exposed to humidity or dust. I also wonder why only the probe has a cap on, but not for the female sockets on the obviously more expensive multimeter itself.

But what are they called? I've tried searching for banana jack shield, banana socket cover, banana connector cap and all sorts of possible mix of keywords I can think of but nothing turns out remotely close to what shown in the picture.

[image: z2]
[image: z3]

Comment: I call them unnecessary plastic trash.

Comment: these equipments are fairly expensive and I assume keeping the socket in good condition is rather essential as they could be difficult to clean. Shouldn't I cover them when they are not in used, especially for the sockets on the benchtop multimeter? I could 3d print them easily but I thought they are standard accessories and I just don't know their name to search for.

Comment: I have never been in a working professional test lab where the banana jacks were covered when the equipment was not in use. In a proper test lab you should not have excessive humidity or dust. If you take your meter into a harsh environment then you need to protect the **entire meter** when not in use. I would worry more about the switches and buttons than the banana jacks.

Comment: I always assumed that were to prevent the probe from sticking you when rummaging around to find it. Not everybody keeps a neat and orderly lab.

Answer (score 2):

Fluke sell these caps like "Amp Jack Plug Set"

[image: Amp Jack Plug Set]

You can also find these in the Chinese Ali Store under the name of "multimeter dust cover protective cap 4.0 socket"

[image: multi meter dust cover protective cap 4.0 socket]